# how do i get rid of the ¦ sign in my data

Tags: r, special-characters, stringr, glyph

I desperately need your help. I scraped some data from wikipedia and I came across this ¦ sign. At first I thought it's just | but but it's obviously not.

Most of my cells looks like this

```
table$Population
7004164110000000000¦16,411[7]
7007111260000000000¦11,126,000[13]
```

I'm trying to remove everything but 16,411, but first I need to how to convert it into something else.

Any help appreciated, I was going nuts because when I tried the gsub function it didn't work and then the str_split_fixed one didn't work either...

`dput(tables$Population)` gives

```
c("7007301655000000000¦30,165,500[6]", "7007241833000000000¦24,183,300[8]", "7007217070000000000¦21,707,000[10]", "7007150292310000000¦15,029,231[11]")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The output of `dput(tables$Population)` in a code block would be more helpful.

Comment: And have a look at gsub

Comment: c("7007301655000000000¦30,165,500[6]", "7007241833000000000¦24,183,300[8]", 
"7007217070000000000¦21,707,000[10]", "7007150292310000000¦15,029,231[11]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to parse that table into a data frame:

```
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population")

html_node(pg, "table.wikitable") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  dplyr::tbl_df() %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% # THE LINE BELOW DOES THE MAGIC YOU ORIGINALLY ASKE FOR BUT IN A DIFFERENT WAY
  tidyr::separate(population, c("sortkey", "population"), sep="[^[:ascii:]]+") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    population = gsub("\\[.*$", "", population)
  ) %>% 
  readr::type_convert()
## # A tibble: 87 x 9
##     rank city      image sortkey population definition                totalarea_km  populationdensi… country
##    <int> <chr>     <lgl>   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>                     <chr>                    <dbl> <chr>  
##  1     1 Chongqing NA    7.01e18  30165500. Municipality              700482403000…             366. China  
##  2     2 Shanghai  NA    7.01e18  24183300. Municipality              700363405000…            3814. China  
##  3     3 Beijing   NA    7.01e18  21707000. Municipality              700416411000…            1267. China  
##  4     4 Istanbul  NA    7.01e18  15029231. Metropolitan municipality 700262029000…           24231. Turkey 
##  5     5 Karachi   NA    7.01e18  14910352. City[14]                  700337800000…            3944. Pakist…
##  6     6 Dhaka     NA    7.01e18  14399000. City                      700233754000…           42659. Bangla…
##  7     7 Guangzhou NA    7.01e18  13081000. City (sub-provincial)     700374340000…            1760. China  
##  8     8 Shenzhen  NA    7.01e18  12528300. City (sub-provincial)     700319920000…            6889. China  
##  9     9 Mumbai    NA    7.01e18  12442373. City[21]                  700243771000…           28426. India  
## 10    10 Moscow    NA    7.01e18  13200000. Federal city[24][25]      2 511[26]                5256. Russia 
## # ... with 77 more rows
```

The table uses the following underlying markup for the rows:

[image]

The "population" cells end up looking like this in an R raw vector (this is the first one, `30` == a space to provide a visual marker reference):

```
## [1] 37 30 30 37 33 30 31 36 35 35 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 e2 99 a0 33 30 2c 31 36 35 2c 35 30 30 5b 36 5d
```

Which looks more like a unicode embedding. Since it's "not ASCII" we can use that to our advantage for wrangling out the data.

Comment: what exactly do the clean_names and type_convert functions do? i want to make sure i understand every step :) again, thank you so much

Comment: `clean_names()` takes the human-oriented column names and transforms them automatically to something more useful in a programmatic context (e.g. 'Total
area (km²)` => `totalarea_km`). `readr::type_convert()` uses heuristics to infer and transform columns. e.g. the oclumns with `"24,183,300"` become a numeric `24183300`. But, you've already accepted the answer which riffed off of mine despite mine providing a more comprehensive solution so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: to be honest, i thought i could check both as solved? i havent used stack overflow before besides googling solutions, sorry for that. you obviously deserve the credit, its fixed now! and thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape with `\\`

```
test <- "7004164110000000000¦16,411"
gsub("\\¦", "", test)
[1] "700416411000000000016,411"
```

EDIT: Yes, it works also for the column:

```
> gsub("\\¦","",c("7007301655000000000¦30,165,500[6]", "7007241833000000000¦24,183,300[8]", "7007217070000000000¦21,707,000[10]", "7007150292310000000¦15,029,231[11]"))
[1] "700730165500000000030,165,500[6]"  "700724183300000000024,183,300[8]" 
[3] "700721707000000000021,707,000[10]" "700715029231000000015,029,231[11]"
```

EDIT2: replacing the character as suggested by @hrbrmstr, the following should work for you:

```
stringr::str_replace(c("7007301655000000000¦30,165,500[6]", "7007241833000000000¦24,183,300[8]", "7007217070000000000¦21,707,000[10]", "7007150292310000000¦15,029,231[11]"),
+                      "[^[:ascii:]]+","")
[1] "700730165500000000030,165,500[6]"  "700724183300000000024,183,300[8]" 
[3] "700721707000000000021,707,000[10]" "700715029231000000015,029,231[11]"
```

Comment: That specific character might not be what ultimately occurs in a given locale since it's unicode on the site (see my answer).